# Delete item from constant array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div box002, On dragging and droping it to any of three class box with randomly selected numbers from a constant array named **array2**, the item should get deleted from array2.

for that i have created object of rvalue() function and tried to remove item in **const filteredItems** but didn't worked.

Where is the mistake,

How to achieve it?

```js
var tempimages = [];


function rvalue() {
  var items = [  
      { label: '1:40', url: '1.png'  },
      { label: '2:20', url: '2.png'  },
      { label: '3:50', url: '3.png'  },
      { label: '4:45', url: '4.png'  },
      { label: '5:35', url: '5.png'  },
      { label: '6:10', url: '6.png'  },
      { label: '7:15', url: '7.png'  },
      { label: '8:10', url: '8.png'  },
      { label: '9:30', url: '9.png'  },
     { label: '10:40', url:'10.png' },
      { label: '11:20', url:'11.png' },
      { label: '12:50', url:'12.png' },
      { label: '01:45', url:'13.png' },
      { label: '02:25', url:'14.png' },
      { label: '03:40', url:'15.png' },
      { label: '04:15', url:'16.png' },
      { label: '05:10', url:'17.png' },
      { label: '06:30', url:'18.png' },
      { label: '07:35', url:'20.png' }
   ]
   
ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');

const array2 = Object.assign([], items);

 


for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) 
     {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length),
      
      item = items[randomIndex];

      ptags[index].textContent = item.label;

      tempimages.push({data:item, index: randomIndex});
   
   ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
    }
 
  
}
 

function displayAllImages() {

  if (tempimages.length === 0) 
  {
    return;
  }
 item = tempimages.shift(),
  
    image = document.getElementById('slide');

    image.src = item.data.url;

    image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
    
};

$(function() {
  
  rvalue();
  displayAllImages(); 
}); 

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();

console.log(ev.srcElement);

var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

var el = document.getElementById(data);

alert(data);

alert(el);

var x=document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;

var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;

alert("x=>" + x + " y=>" + y);
  
 if(x==y)
  {
 //alert("go");
  el.parentNode.removeChild; 

  
  ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; 

  var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
  
   var ob1=new rvalue();
   var delitem=ob1.item;
   var filteredItems = array2.filter(item => item!== valueToRemove)
  
  
   console.log(filteredItems);
   console.log(delitem);
  
  
  
  displayAllImages();
  }
  else{
  alert("WRONG PLACE");
  }
}
```

```css
.box002 {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
         border:2px solid #333;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11"><p name="values"></p></div>
                <div class="box"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12"><p name="values"></p></div>
            </div>
            
    
<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
 <img src=""  draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:120px; height:120px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "not work": Did you get an error message, freeze, unexpected behavior or something else? Have you run your code in a debugger to see which line it misbehaves on?

Comment: @haem no i diddn't,  is  const filteredItems  is what i have to use to get the desired output

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Answer (score 1):

Because of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) you can't change a constant, since they're... constant

> The value of a constant cannot change through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.
>
> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

To be able to alter any entry in your array, just make it a var or a let-variable.